# Is R is connected subspace of R2.?

Tags: connectedness

1st I want to know , is R is a subspace of R2? 
Because R can be written as R×{0} which is a subset of R2.

Comment: No, it is not a subspace at all.

Comment: It depends on how you wish to think about $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is connected.  It is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^2$.  You are done once you decide whether that is what you mean by "subspace".

Answer (score 2):

So, you're asking a question which is a lot deeper than you might think. The short and sweet is that $\mathbb{R}$ is one dimensional, but in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have 2 dimensions. So, $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ is a 1 dimensional subspace of a 2 dimensional space, the fact that it is a *subspace* of a 2 dimensional space is important information we'd like to keep. To get a better grasp of this concept, I suggest reading the book *Flatland* by Edwin Abbott Abbott.

Now, in a more technical sense, what you're asking about is something called a morphism. In our case, we would say, in plain english, that $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ is *basically* $\mathbb{R}$. It behaves and acts just like it, however it is *not* $\mathbb{R}$, it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that looks just like $\mathbb{R}$. You would be incorrect, or at least remiss, to say that this *is* $\mathbb{R}$.

Welcome to the beauty and elegance of Mathematics! :)

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ is 1 dimensional since a basis only has 1 element

Comment: Well, it spans a 1 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, sure. However, it is still two dimensional because it lives within a two dimensional space. You can't tell me that it's 1 dimensional. How do you write an element of $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$? Would you agree that it looks like $\{(x, 0) | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: It is not two dimensional. The correct way of saying is it is a 1 dimensional subspace of a 2 dimensional space.

Comment: That's fair. I can agree that it is a 1 dimensional subspace, and thus 1 dimensional. I guess I'm more focusing on the fact that it comes from a 2 dimensional space which is important information in saying that $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ isn't $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I satisfied with the answer with Sir Blake, Sir I want to know R×{0} is connected in R2.?

Comment: @SubhasishChowdhury well, it depends on what your notion of connected is. If you mean topologically, then you need to ask if it is the union of two disjoint, non empty sets. If it isn’t, then we consider it to be connected :)